# xquery "last" function with other selectors

Tags: xquery

I am curious how to use the `last()` function in Xquery along with other "selectors" (not sure of the correct lingo). Here is what I have (and this works):

```
for $lastscoreplay in //bbgame/plays/period[last()]/play[@action="GOOD"]

return <datarow>

<lastscoreplay>{data($lastscoreplay/@uni)}</lastscoreplay>

</datarow>
```

But, I want to select the last `play` where the `@action` equals `GOOD`. If that makes sense. I would think I could do this but it does not work:

```
for $lastscoreplay in //bbgame/plays/period[last()]/play[last()][@action="GOOD"]

return <datarow>

<lastscoreplay>{data($lastscoreplay/@uni)}</lastscoreplay>

</datarow>
```

Sorry I am still rather new to Xquery and coding in general so sorry if this is easy and I just don't see the problem. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should provide a sample XML file, it makes easier to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dzgxaepoyq3p5u/ISU03.XML) to the XML I am working with. There is quite a bit to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You query get's the last play, *regardless of `@action`*, and then filters that last play by `[@action="GOOD"]`. Instead, you should first filter by `@action`, then get the last one:

```
 //bbgame/plays/period[last()]/play[@action="GOOD"][last()]
```

The full query:

```
for $lastscoreplay in //bbgame/plays/period[last()]/play[@action="GOOD"][last()]
return
  <datarow>
    <lastscoreplay>{ data($lastscoreplay/@uni) }</lastscoreplay>
  </datarow>
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too but it still doesn't work. I am using this within another program and when I run it with both the `[@action="GOOD"]` and `[last()]` it returns an empty output. If I just leave the `[@action="GOOD"]`, it works fine, it is just returning all of the plays with `[@action="GOOD"]`. Could you think of another way to complete this within Xquery? Maybe it is this program (graphic CG program called CharacterWorks) that just doesn't like how I am doing it.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dzgxaepoyq3p5u/ISU03.XML) to the XML I am working with. Maybe that will help?

Comment: The answer actually works for this XML (both xpath and xquery), and it returns 31 (the value of uni attribute of that play element). So it might have to do with your processor or configuration of processor. Can you try setting a variable with the sequence then selecting the last item, like this: `let $all := //bbgame/plays/period[last()]/play[@action="GOOD"]
return $all[last()]`

for is actually not needed for this.

Comment: Thank you @luciddream! I swear I tried that but after trying again as you posted, it worked! I am guessing it is the processor the software I am using is using. I am sure what @joemfb posted works, just not in the software I am using. Thanks again!

Comment: That's good to know! I've been puzzled with something like this before. I will add my comment as an answer just for reference, no need to accept mine.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the accepted answer won't work, if that happens try this alternative:

```
let $all := /bbgame/plays/period[last()]/play[@action="GOOD"]
return $all[last()]
```